# iOS 8, Xcode 6 tab bar image tint

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

When I select a `UIColor` for `UIImage` tint in the `UITabBar` properties, nothing change, only default blue is shown. I need to call

```
[[UITabBar appearance] 
  setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 
                                            green:150.0/255.0 
                                             blue:10.0/255.0 
                                            alpha:1.0]];
```

but it's not called on start of the application so the icon is initially blue and change it's color in a second time (even if put in `viewWillAppear`).

I use as launch screen file the `UIStoryboard` which has the `UITabBarController` inside.

Any ideas? 
Did the selection of the image tint in `xcode 6` works via `UIInterfaceBuilder`?

Thanks

Comment: I also tried with a new project, the selected image tint color doesn't change if set via interface builder.... bug?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is a bug.

you can solve this by using "User Defined Runtime Attributes" to change tabBar.tintColor(for >= iOS7) or tabBar.selectedImageTintColor(for all, but depressed in iOS 8).

Don't using Attributes Inspector. (It do not work)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your appearance call, use `setTintColor` instead of `setSelectedImageTintColor`.